# Polynomials and the inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given $P(x) = c_mX^m + c_{m-1}X^{m-1} +...+c_1X+c_0$ , and$ G(x) = c_0X^m + c_{1}X^{m-1} +...+c_{m-1}X+c_m$.
>
> Also given an invertible matrix $A \in M_{n \times n} {(F)}$, and $c_0,...,c_m \in F$.
>
> (I) Prove that $P(A) = 0$ **iff** $G(A^{-1}) = 0$.
>
> (II) Given $ m_A(X) = X^3 - 2X + 7$, find $m_{A^{-1}}(X)$

I have no direction whatsoever, I would appreciate any help!

Comment: For the first, how would you go about it if it weren't matrices but real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $P(A)=0$, this means $c_mA^m+c_{m-1}A^{m-1}+\cdots+c_1A+c_0=0$. Let's multiply from the left with $A^{-m}$. That would then be $c_m+c_{m-1}A^{-1}+\cdots+c_1A^{-(m-1)}+c_0 A^{-m}=0$. That's exactly $G(A^{-1})=0$. The argument is completely symmetric, so that settles (I). I honestly don't understand (II), because $A$ seems to play no role in the definition $m_A(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

@Jesko, $m_A$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. So if $A$ satisfies the equation $A^3-2A+7I=0$, the same argument as above shows that $I - 2(A^{-1})^2 + 7((A^{-1})^3 = 0$. So if $A$ has minimal polynomial $P$, $A^{-1}$ has minimal polynomial $G$. (Why can it not be a polynomial of lower degree?)

Comment: Still can't find a reason why it can't be a polynomial of a lower degree

Comment: @TheNotMe: Wouldn't that give you a lower degree polynomial that $A$ satisfies?